# how to write cmake with 1 executable and multiple subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, exec, subdirectory

I have a project with many sub-directories that each 1 of them include both header and source files.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              I want 1 executable which include all my src files.
I managed to write the cmake so it compiles successfully,
but Im dealing with 2 problems, I dont now how to solve:
1 - The compile time is **very slow**, probably somthing I'm doing wrong.
2 - I have few flags like DEBUG, RELEASE that I couldnt make it define/ undefine in any of the     CMakeLists.txt files.
I need this because I have some of my source files :
`#ifndef RELEASE /DEBUG #endif`

My project stracture looks similar to this:

```
root/ (project root)
    3rd_party/
        spdlog/ ...
    src/
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp (contains main method)
        logger/
            log.c
            logger.cpp
            logger.hpp 
            CMakeLists.txt
        first/
            first_c.h
            first.cpp
            first.hpp 
            CMakeLists.txt
        second/
            second.cpp
            second.hpp 
            CMakeLists.txt
        control/
            control.cpp
            control.hpp 
            control_2.hpp 
            CMakeLists.txt
        some more sub directories/...
    build/
        ... (executable)
```

This is part from what I currently have :

in src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(integration LANGUAGES CXX)

set(src_main main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(first)
add_subdirectory(second)
add_subdirectory(third)
add_subdirectory(control)
add_subdirectory(logger) 
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../3rd_party/spdlog ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src_main})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  control first second third logger) 

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC RELEASE) # not working???
```

in src/control/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(control_source_files
  control.cpp
  control.hpp
)

add_library(control SHARED ${control_source_files})

find_library(LIB paho-mqtt3c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)


target_link_libraries(control PUBLIC Threads::Threads) 
target_link_libraries(control PUBLIC ${LIB})

target_include_directories(robot_control PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../second)
target_include_directories(robot_control PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third)
```

in src/first/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(first_source_files
  first_c.h
  first.cpp
  first.hpp
)

add_library(first SHARED ${first_source_files})

target_include_directories(motor PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../second)
target_include_directories(motor PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../logger)
target_include_directories(motor PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rd_party/date/include/)
```

Im not sure if I need `target_include_directories` I did it becuase in first.hpp there are icludes for headers in those subdirectories.

any help to do the compile time faster and define right the flags ??

Comment: I did separte to multiple target, as I wrote an example of the CmakeList.txt of first & control sub-directories.   
In all the CmakeList.txt appear in the sub-directories I use add library 
the loger cmake is: 
```set(logger_source_files
  log.h
  logger.cpp
  logger.hpp)                                                                                                                                 
add_library(logger STATIC ${logger_source_files})                                                                             
target_link_libraries(logger spdlog::spdlog)
```
@MarekR

Comment: I recommend watch https://youtu.be/YbgH7yat-Jo It is best explanation how good cmake starting project should look like. Not sure if [this is respective git repo](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/gui_starter_template).

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - The compile time is very slow, probably somthing I'm doing wrong.

There might be many reasons.

Main cause is usually to many includes in header files. Froward declarations in as many places as possible of header files is very effective cure for that issue. There is even a tool which helps to clean up existing project Include What You Use (IWYU).

---

> 2 - I have few flags like DEBUG, RELEASE that I couldnt make it
> define/ undefine in any of the CMakeLists.txt files. I need this
> because I have some of my source files :

> ```
> target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC RELEASE) # not working???
> ```

You are doing that wrong. Depending on generator you use (if it supports multiple configuration or not), you can control this in configuration step or in build step, by passing extra parameters:

In case if generator do not have mtuple configurations you configure this this way:

```
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build .
```

[See doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Packaging%20Debug%20and%20Release.html)

If generator supports multiple configurations then:

```
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

---

> ```
> target_include_directories(robot_control PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../second)
> target_include_directories(robot_control PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third)
> ```

This is wrong. `target_include_directories` defines which paths are important for given target (library). Now when something is `PUBLIC` then any target which will do `target_link_libraries(someTarget PUBLIC sourceTarget)` where `sourceTarget` is your library will be impacted by this path. `someTarget` will inherit include paths from public (or interface) of source target so you don't have to add them explicitly.

So basically this quted lines are obsolete (if `second` and `third` targets have this include paths defined as PUBLIC).

Comment: The way I use to compile it is:

Comment: The way I use to compile the exec is:
```mkdir build
cmake -S src -B build```
than:
```cd build
make```
thats because all of my subdirectorues appear under src dir and I created a build directory only for the build. 
when I do in root/: ```cmake -S src -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug``` its build correctly but in my program it still seems like the DEBUG flag is undefine.
Also I read that cmake support multiple configuration but I dont want to use them because I might have another defined flags like DEVELOP_MODE etc.. @MarekR